# Magento 2: Reviews product

Tags: magento2, review, product-review

Currently, reviews for each product only display assigned to one product. https://prnt.sc/rhmt1q

Any solution to display all opinions in this tab from the website and add above each opinion the name of the product to which the opinion relates?

We sell clothing, so the products change dynamically and are not likely to return the same models. 
That is why we want to display all opinions from the website.

Comment: You mean every product's review will display in that tab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please override the file:

> Magento/vendor/magento/module-review/Block/Product/View.php

Find:

```
public function getReviewsCollection()
{
    if (null === $this->_reviewsCollection) {
        $this->_reviewsCollection = $this->_reviewsColFactory->create()->addStoreFilter(
            $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId()
        )->addStatusFilter(
            \Magento\Review\Model\Review::STATUS_APPROVED
        )->addEntityFilter(
            'product',
            $this->getProduct()->getId()
        )->setDateOrder();
    }
    return $this->_reviewsCollection;
}
```

and replace it with:

```
public function getReviewsCollection()
{
    if (null === $this->_reviewsCollection) {
        $this->_reviewsCollection = $this->_reviewsColFactory->create()->addStoreFilter(
            $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId()
        )->addStatusFilter(
            \Magento\Review\Model\Review::STATUS_APPROVED
        )->setDateOrder();
    }
    return $this->_reviewsCollection;
}
```

you can see that I removed addEntityFilter for productId which is use for the validation.

Let me know if you need any further help

Comment: Thank you. Work perfect. I accept your answear. Last case. Is any solution how to get product name assigned to a given review? https://prnt.sc/rhodfq because each review relates to different products and I would like to display the product name with a link to product redirection like here:  https://prnt.sc/rhoeu0

Comment: @Sylvester ask a new question for it, so anyone can help

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/307261/magento2-how-to-get-product-name-above-review