# Magento2: How to get product name above review

Tags: magento2, review

In tab review, we display all reviews available in our website.

how to get product name assigned to a given review? https://prnt.sc/rhodfq because each review relates to different products and I would like to display the product name with a link to product redirection like here: https://prnt.sc/rhoeu0

Comment: hi, where you need it?

Comment: please check my answer

Comment: Please ask a question in detail, so it is helpful for others in the future

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try below code:

replace code on file

vendor/magento/module-review/view/frontend/templates/product/view/list.phtml

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

/** @var Magento\Review\Block\Product\View\ListView $block */

$_items = $block->getReviewsCollection()->getItems();
$format = $block->getDateFormat() ?: \IntlDateFormatter::SHORT;

$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

$appState = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Framework\App\State');

$registry = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Framework\Registry');
$currentProduct = $registry->registry('current_product');
$product_name = $currentProduct->getName();
$product_url = $currentProduct->getProductUrl();


?>
<?php if (count($_items)):?>
<div class="block review-list" id="customer-reviews">
    <div class="block-title">
        <strong><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Customer Reviews')) ?></strong>
    </div>
    <div class="block-content">
        <div class="toolbar review-toolbar">
            <?= $block->getChildHtml('toolbar') ?>
        </div>
        <ol class="items review-items">
        <?php foreach ($_items as $_review):?>
            <li class="item review-item" itemscope itemprop="review" itemtype="http://schema.org/Review">
                <p><a href="<?php echo $product_url; ?>"><?php echo $product_name; ?></a></p>
                <div class="review-title" itemprop="name"><?= $block->escapeHtml($_review->getTitle()) ?></div>
                <?php if (count($_review->getRatingVotes())): ?>
                    <div class="review-ratings">
                    <?php foreach ($_review->getRatingVotes() as $_vote): ?>
                    <div class="rating-summary item" itemprop="reviewRating" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Rating">
                        <span class="label rating-label"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml($_vote->getRatingCode()) ?></span></span>
                        <div class="rating-result" title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($_vote->getPercent()) ?>%">
                            <meta itemprop="worstRating" content = "1"/>
                            <meta itemprop="bestRating" content = "100"/>
                            <span style="width:<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($_vote->getPercent()) ?>%">
                                <span itemprop="ratingValue"><?= $block->escapeHtml($_vote->getPercent()) ?>%</span>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </div>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <div class="review-content" itemprop="description">
                    <?= nl2br($block->escapeHtml($_review->getDetail())) ?>
                </div>
                <div class="review-details">
                    <p class="review-author">
                        <span class="review-details-label"><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Review by')) ?></span>
                        <strong class="review-details-value" itemprop="author"><?= $block->escapeHtml($_review->getNickname()) ?></strong>
                    </p>
                    <p class="review-date">
                        <span class="review-details-label"><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Posted on')) ?></span>
                        <time class="review-details-value" itemprop="datePublished" datetime="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->formatDate($_review->getCreatedAt(), $format)) ?>"><?= $block->escapeHtml($block->formatDate($_review->getCreatedAt(), $format)) ?></time>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ol>
        <div class="toolbar review-toolbar">
            <?= $block->getChildHtml('toolbar') ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<?php endif;?>
```

Or for different product per review

```
<?php
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $product = $objectManager->create("Magento\Catalog\Model\Product")->load($_review->getEntityPkValue()); 
     ?>
     <a href="<?= $product->getProductUrl() ?>"><?= $product->getName() ?></a>
```

Hope it works!

Comment: Please open our produkt card and click on tab "Opinie". https://gerris.pl/z1102200b04700-3199-l-3199-tinta-unita-bc2c6b3a8db0711c05a827151d7db3f8.html

Comment: ok wait let me check

Comment: In this TAB we display all reviews from all products. We need: How to display product name above each review (because each review is for a different product) https://prnt.sc/rhodfq

Comment: okay got it for this I need FTP access or theme files.

Comment: or I can please let me know you added theme for that or extension?

Comment: just tell me theme or extension?

Comment: Claue Theme. We do not use extension. All changes we do in  Magento/vendor/magento/module-review and work correct and display in frondend

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105639/discussion-between-sarvesh-dineshkumar-patel-and-sylvester).

Answer (score 0):

Override the File:

> Magento/vendor/magento/module-review/view/frontend/templates/product/view/list.phtml

find the  `<?php foreach ($_items as $_review) :?>` after that add

```
     <?php
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $product = $objectManager->create("Magento\Catalog\Model\Product")->load($_review->getEntityPkValue()); 
     ?>
     <a href="<?= $product->getProductUrl() ?>"><?= $product->getName() ?></a>
```

Please don't use **objectManager**, create a block instead. I am just providing you a logic.

Comment: You are also right bro.